# Validator::make($req->all(), $rules); in laravel 8, failed and just keep throwing error in postman

Tags: laravel, api, validation

Am new here and am studying laravel 8, and currently in API validation, the problem is even though am coding along in the tutorials, am not getting the result as the tutor in the tutorials, mine is giving errors right from the vs code editor, this is the line code:

```
$validator = Validator::make($req->all(), $rules);
```

[image: API Validation]

Please is there other ways to validate a post API in laravel 8 or am i missing anything , i need assistance, thanks

Comment: is there an actual PHP error when you run the code? as your editor isn't running your code

Comment: [Post code instead image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#answer-285557).

Comment: It is not an error, it is saying that the class Validator cannot be found, but Laravel have aliases, so `Validator` IS going to work (just run the code....). Still, you should be using `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator` instead of plain `Validator`

Answer (score 4):

On line 7 of your code in the linked picture, change:

`use Validator;`

to:

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;`